# progress circle UIControll iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, progress

Anybody know how to make progress indicator of doing something like on a screenshot? [image]

Answer (score 0):

There are mainly two way to do this:

1. Create and save many images with the progress indicator in various positions. Then use  `UIImageView` to display it, changing the image accordingly to the current progress. This is a easy solution, however it requires you to create (manually) the various images. Besides it's not continuos (even if it can be smooth enough, according to the number of images you save). However, it can give a good effect (according to your needs).
2. Draw the indicator at runtime. In your case it should not be so hard since your progress indicator is very simple. Take a look at [CGContext](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=cgcontext%20&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http://developer.apple.com/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html&ei=CcyFT6avPMuQ4gSXp8nPBw&usg=AFQjCNEjD0g71ChGkD27r-RsBKiU3W408g&sig2=rtiAQ5kTfJttMQfrSheMaw), it will provide all the method to draw a circle, draw lines and fill a path with a color. This will give a better result than the previous solution, however it requires the indicator to be redrawn every time.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [TKAProgressCircleView](https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary/tree/master/src/TapkuLibrary). Does exactly what you need, I use it myself in couple of apps.